# Executing a symbolic link yields different results than executing the file to which it points

Tags: symlink, executable

## The context

I've downloaded `scilab-6.1.0.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz` from the [official website of "Scilab"](https://www.scilab.org/download/6.1.0) because I want to be able to use the provided tools.

Within the `bin` directory of the downloaded files, I've the following files

```
$ ls -l | cut -d ' ' -f 5-

1713591 Feb 25 05:27 modelicac
2057719 Feb 25 05:27 modelicat
  44563 Feb 25 05:27 scilab
      6 Feb 25 05:27 scilab-adv-cli -> scilab
  24741 Feb 25 05:27 scilab-bin
      6 Feb 25 05:27 scilab-cli -> scilab
  20725 Feb 25 05:27 scilab-cli-bin
  44563 Feb 25 05:27 scinotes
  44563 Feb 25 05:27 xcos
 675942 Feb 25 05:27 XML2Modelica

$ test -L scilab-adv-cli && test -L scilab-cli && echo $?
0
```

As we can see, both `scilab-cli` and `scilab-adv-cli` are symbolic links to `scilab`. Executing `scilab-cli`, `scilab-adv-cli` and `scilab` yields to different results (see gif below)

[image]

## The question

Isn't a symbolic link **(A)** , which points to an executable **(B)**, be supposed to execute **(B)**?

In the scenario presented above, `scilab-cli` and `scilab-adv-cli` would be **(A)** and `scilab` would be **(B)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a symlink which points to an executable does indeed run the executable, but there is one important difference: the first argument given to the new process, which (in this case) stores the command given, gives the name of the symlink, not the name of the target executable. This allows programs to implement different behaviours depending on how they’re called.

One common instance which is likely to be installed on your system is `apropos`: it’s typically (on Linux systems at least) a symlink to `whatis`, but the two commands behave differently.

In your case, when `scilab` is run as `scilab-cli`, it presents its text-mode interface; when it’s run as `scilab` (as happens with your `realpath` approach), it starts its GUI.

Comment: I didn't think about that. A good way of explaining this is through a single bash script which contains a conditional that compares the value of `$0` with the name of a regular file and the names of its corresponding symbolic links.